# Путь к рабочему столу

Tags: bat

Почему не создается файл на рабочем столе?

```
echo TEXT > %SYSTEMDRIVE%%HOMEPATH%\FileName.txt
```

Comment: Потому что `%HOMEPATH%` - это не рабочий стол, это домашняя директория: `echo %SYSTEMDRIVE%%HOMEPATH%` выдает в моем случае `C:\Users\computer`.

Comment: @insolor, почему не ответом?

Comment: @insolor точно, спасибо, не досмотрел

Comment: @Grundy, перенес в ответ.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Потому что `%HOMEPATH%` - это не рабочий стол, это домашняя директория: `echo %SYSTEMDRIVE%%HOMEPATH%` выдает в моем случае `C:\Users\computer`

В вашем случае файл создастся в вашей домашней директории, но не на рабочем столе.

Comment: %SYSTEMDRIVE%%HOMEPATH%\Desktop\FileName.txt.
Я так сделал